# Regular expression taking too much time to compile in R

Tags: regex, r, time-complexity, text-mining

I read a file in ratingsFile using

```
ratingsFile <- readLines("~/ratings.list",encoding = "UTF-8")
```

The file's first few lines looks like

```
  0000000125  1478759   9.2  The Shawshank Redemption (1994)
  0000000125  1014575   9.2  The Godfather (1972)
  0000000124  683611   9.0  The Godfather: Part II (1974)
  0000000124  1451861   8.9  The Dark Knight (2008)
  0000000124  1150611   8.9  Pulp Fiction (1994)
  0000000133  750978   8.9  Schindler's List (1993)
```

Using regular expression I extracted

```
  match <- gregexpr("[0-9A-Za-z;'$%&?@./]+",ratingsFile)
  match <- regmatches(ratingsFile,match)


  next_match <- gregexpr("[0-9][.][0-9]+",ratingsFile)
  next_match <- regmatches(ratingsFile,next_match)
```

The sample output of match looks like

```
  "0000000125" "1014575"    "9.2"        "The"        "Godfather"  "1972"
```

For cleaning that data and changing to the form i need I did

```
  movies_name <- character(0)
  rating <- character(0)
  for(i in 1:length(match)){

      match[[i]]<-match[[i]][-1:-3] #for removing not need cols 
      len <- length(match[[i]])
      match[[i]]<-match[[i]][-len]#removing last column also not needed
      movies_name<-append(movies_name,paste(match[[i]],collapse =" "))
      #appending movies name
      rating <- append(rating,next_match[[i]]) 
      #appending rating
}
```

Now this final block of code is taking too long to execute.I have left he compilation process for hours but still it is not completed as the file is  636497 lines long.

How can i reduce the compilation time in this case?

Comment: could you describe exactly what you want to do? (instead of wanting us to guess, reading your code)

Comment: I want to reduce the compilation time of last block of code.

Comment: I figured that out but can you tell what this block is doing and, even better, what exactly you want to do so we can show you how to do it more efficiently = maybe just speed up the last loop but more likely, replace the last loop and maybe also steps before by something more efficient that would do the same thing...

Comment: Sir, I did some editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ratingsFile <- readLines(n = 6)
0000000125  1478759   9.2  The Shawshank Redemption (1994)
0000000125  1014575   9.2  The Godfather (1972)
0000000124  683611   9.0  The Godfather: Part II (1974)
0000000124  1451861   8.9  The Dark Knight (2008)
0000000124  1150611   8.9  Pulp Fiction (1994)
0000000133  750978   8.9  Schindler's List (1993)
setNames(as.data.frame(t(sapply(regmatches(ratingsFile, regexec("\\d{10}\\s+\\d+\\s+([0-9.]+)\\s+(.*?)\\s\\(\\d{4}\\)", ratingsFile)), "[", -1))), c("rating", "movie_name"))
#   rating               movie_name
# 1    9.2 The Shawshank Redemption
# 2    9.2            The Godfather
# 3    9.0   The Godfather: Part II
# 4    8.9          The Dark Knight
# 5    8.9             Pulp Fiction
# 6    8.9         Schindler's List
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you want to do (only get the movie titles), here is another option to get what you want:

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(ratingsFile, "\\s{2,}"), # split each line whenever there are at least 2 spaces
                                 function(x){ # for each resulting vector
                                    x <- gsub(" \\(\\d{4}\\)$", "", tail(x, 1)) # keep only the needed part (movie title)
                                    x
                                 }))

# [1] "The Shawshank Redemption" "The Godfather"            "The Godfather: Part II"   "The Dark Knight"          "Pulp Fiction"            
# [6] "Schindler's List"
```

**NB:** Note that you can put the resulting vector in a data.frame and/or keep the other information from the former lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find and use some data from your data, I think you can use this regex:

```
/^ *(\d*) *(\d*) *(\d+\.\d+)(.*)\((\d+)\)$/gm
```

with substitutions

- $1 => first column
- $2 => second column
- $3 => third column (maybe rating)
- $4 => movie name
- $5 => movie year

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/nL2xC6/1)